# In Linux how do I start up Atmel Studio

Tags: arduino-uno, linux, atmel-studio

I am using Linux Fedora 20. In order to compile C programs for the Arduino, as described in the book "C Programming with Arduino" by Warwick A Smith, pub by Elektor, I have downloaded and untarred/unzipped "avr8-gnu-toolchain-3.5.1.1671-linux.any.x86.tar.gz". That's as far as I can get. Please how do I proceed from this point? Is there anything else I need or should have done?

Comment: What you have there is the compiler. If you want the IDE you should download and install the IDE.

Comment: You do not need atmel studio to do C development for the AVR - you can use any text editor or configurable IDE along with a toolchain such as avr-gcc (possibly what you just downloaded).  You can even "borrow" the version of avr-gcc (and if you like, also avrdude) installed by the Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 1):

https://mil.ufl.edu/374/docs/Install_Atmel_Studio_7.0.pdf :

Note for Mac and Linux Computer Users

If you have a Mac (i.e., a Macintosh computer from Apple) or if you use Linux, you will need an alternate Windows installation
or you will need to install a Windows virtual machine in order to then install and run Atmel Studio.

We suggest that you install
Boot Camp (free and the best); Parallels (not free) or possibly VMware (not free) may also work. UF offers free copies of
Windows 10 Software.

We do not recommend Virtual Box. Wine is another alternative, but this has not been verified to work.
(Note: My best students use Boot Camp!)

Comment: Why not VirtualBox?  Any specific reason?

Answer (score -1):

Atmel Studio is a windows only product.
The only way to run it on linux is in a virtual machine running windows.

Comment: See http://www.atmel.com/tools/ATMELAVRTOOLCHAINFORLINUX.aspx

Comment: De toolchain maar niet de studio. De toochain is puur commandline terwijl de studio eigenlijk microsoft visual studio is met een plugin.